# PostgreSQL insert record by trigger

Tags: postgresql, trigger

```
create table tab1(id int,name text);
create table tab2(id int,name text);

  create or replace function t_tab() returns trigger
as
$$
begin
insert into tab2
values (new.id, new.name)
return new;     
end;
$$
language plpgsql;

create trigger t_tab
after insert on tab1
for each row
execute procedure t_tab();
```

The statement:

```
insert into tab1(1,'king');
```

inserts data in both tables tab1 and tab2.

Now my question is: I want same thing in tab2 table. When I insert data in tab2 table automatically insert same data in tab1. If I create same trigger function in tab2 then the execution unlimited. Is there any solution to fix this?

Comment: Why don't you use a single table?

Comment: because tab1 and tab2 access two different user

Comment: Then use views to give access to a subset of the table, or row level security

Comment: Misguided. Why don't you ask a question on the site detailing the need/requirement for separate tables, and we can give you advice?

Answer (score 2):

assuming ID is a primary key.

`on conflict do nothing`:

```
create or replace function t2_tab() returns trigger
as
$$declare r record;
begin
insert into tab2                                 
select new.*
on conflict do nothing
returning * into r;
return r;    
end;                
$$ language plpgsql;
```